# Automatically execute a macrop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a VBA macro which triggers another macro after changing the value of a cell. This is what I came up with.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("n7")) Is Nothing Then Macro1
End Sub
```

However it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it works fine for me. Are you aware, that this code should be implemented in Sheet section, not Module, and it triggers an `Macro1` only when cell `N7` in this particular Worksheet have changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, this code needs to be in the worksheet you are trying to modify cell "N7" and then call Macro1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N7")) Is Nothing Then Call Macro1
End Sub
```

Example of Sub `Macro1`, located in another code module:

```
Sub Macro1()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```